# Eclipse neon automatically closes when installed Spring tool suite

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

My eclipse was working properly before installing spring tool suite but after installing Spring tool suite it's opening and closing automatically. I am using **jdk8 my system is 32 bit windows** in eclipse log file it's printing following I didn't understood this log what's the problem ?

```
Current thread (0x0217c400):  JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_native, id=3516, stack(0x00030000,0x00130000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x8c29f0ed

Registers:
EAX=0x999f11f6, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x0012db0f, EDX=0x779564f4
ESP=0x0012dc04, EBP=0x0012dc34, ESI=0x8c29f0ed, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x8c29f0ed, EFLAGS=0x00010286

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0012dc04)
0x0012dc04:   73286ef2 732da19d 00000000 73286f00
0x0012dc14:   00000007 7334069c 00000000 00000000
0x0012dc24:   73340ad0 0012dd38 00000000 100232ec
0x0012dc34:   0012dc70 73286e9e 732b37a4 0012dd38
0x0012dc44:   00000000 00000000 73286e91 5e6087b6
0x0012dc54:   0012dd38 00000000 00000000 73340324
0x0012dc64:   0012dc94 7333b404 00000000 0012dca0
0x0012dc74:   73286a4c 5e608766 0012dd38 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x8c29f0ed)
0x8c29f0cd:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xc0000005]
```

Comment: Looks like a JVM crash in native code. The truncated log content you posted has not enough information to determine why the JVM crashed. The log might contain more information than what you posted which could help pinpoint more precisely what code was running when the crash happened.

Comment: it looks like the dashboard with its JavaFX code is responsible for this crash. Here is a workaround described that allows you to disable that JavaFX piece and get STS up and running: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4394